# Property of Kulkarni-Nomizu product

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

I am reading about Weyl tensor in *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds* by John M. Lee. In Lema 7.22 (e), there is the next assertion.

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space endowed with a scalar product $g$, let $h$ and $k$ be symmetric $2$-tensors on V, let T be and algebraic curvatura tensor on $V$, and let tr_g denote the trace on the first and las indices. Then $g(T,h \mathbin{\bigcirc\mspace{-15mu}\wedge\mspace{3mu}} g)=4g(tr_g T,h)$.

$\mathbin{\bigcirc\mspace{-15mu}\wedge\mspace{3mu}}$ denotes de Kulkarni-Nomizu product.
I am a bit lost in my try of the proof, what is the meaning for the metric applied on $(0,4)$ covariant tensors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inner products of tensors are explained in Proposition 2.40.

To get started on the proof, try the strategy I used in the proof of part (b): expand everything in terms of a basis.

Answer (score 2):

When I did that problem, I furthermore chose a basis $ \left(b_i \right)$ for $V$ with respect to which the matrix for $g$ consists of entries of the form $\pm\delta_{ij}$. It made the computation easier since the product $\langle T,h\mathbin{\bigcirc\mspace{-15mu}\wedge\mspace{3mu}} g\rangle _g$ can then be written in coordinates as
$$\langle T,h\mathbin{\bigcirc\mspace{-15mu}\wedge\mspace{3mu}} g\rangle _g=\sum_{i,j,l,m=1}^{n}{T_{ijlm} \left(h_{im}g_{jl}+h_{jl}g_{im}-h_{il}g_{jm}-h_{jm}g_{il} \right)}g^{ii}g^{jj}g^{ll}g^{mm}.$$
Now distribute and show that each of the four resultant sums equals $\langle {\rm tr}_g{T},h\rangle _g$.